# Loading unstructured CSV data into Hive

Tags: csv, hive

I would like to load a CSV file that contains 250000 posts from Stack Exchange into Hive. The CSV takes the following format:

```
    Id  Score   ViewCount   ParentId    Body    DisplayName rnk
```

Every field is delimited by a "," but the field that screws everything up is Body.

Body contains the contents of the top 250000 posts on the website so there's all sort of characters in there, so there's one post per row with 250000 rows.

I've read up on Serde and Regexp but I am still getting null values in my Hive table.

```
    CREATE TABLE dataStore(Id string, Score string, ViewCount string,     ParentId string, Body String, DisplayName String, Rank String)
    ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
    WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
    "separatorChar" = ",",
    "quoteChar"     = """",
    "escapeChar"    = "\"
    )  
    STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally use [ogrodnek's serde](https://github.com/ogrodnek/csv-serde), you might have more luck with that. Also I don't think you're escaping your special character properly, I believe you need

```
"quoteChar"     = "\"",
"escapeChar"    = "\\"
```

Comment: Thanks maxymoo, I tried using Ogrodnek's serde in my code: ROW     FORMAT SERDE 'com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde' but I received a cannot validate error relating to com.bizo.... I guess I need to install the jar file for this to work. Do you know how I can install this JAR file on the Hortonworks Sandbox on the Azure cloud?

Comment: do you have ssh access to the box where hive is running? (i haven't used azure so don't know what the setup is like). if you do, just copy the jar to your home directory, and then at the start of your hive script run `add jar /home/hadoop/hive/csv-serde-1.1.2-0.11.0-all.jar`